# Change cell color on Gridview based on condition using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to change the color of the cell if the balance is less than zero then make it red.  I am getting this error:

```
Input string was not in a correct format.
```

and here is my gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvTest" runat="server" Width="700px" CssClass="table table-hover table-bordered table-responsive" OnRowDataBound = "OnRowDataBound"
                        AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="ID"
                        AllowPaging="true"
                        OnPageIndexChanging="OnPaging_gvBookKeeping"
                        PageSize="25">
                        <Columns>
                          <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" HtmlEncode="true" />
                          <asp:BoundField DataField="FullName" HeaderText="Name" HtmlEncode="true" />

                          <asp:BoundField DataField="Remaining_Ballance" DataFormatString="{0:C0}" HeaderText="Remaining Ballance" HtmlEncode="true" />
                          <asp:BoundField DataField="Note" HeaderText="Note" HtmlEncode="true" />
                          <asp:BoundField DataField="fully_paid" HeaderText="Fully Paid" HtmlEncode="true" />

                          <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="30px" HeaderText="Edit Link">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                              <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkEdit" CausesValidation="false" runat="server" Text="Edit" OnClick="Edit"></asp:LinkButton>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                          </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#E5E5E5" />

                        <PagerSettings Position="TopAndBottom" />
                        <PagerStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" ForeColor="#FF3300" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                      </asp:GridView>
```

here is code behind

```
protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

  if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
  {
    TableCell cell = e.Row.Cells[2];
    int ballance = int.Parse(cell.Text);
    if (ballance < 0)
    {
      cell.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
  }
}
```

it is failing at this line

```
int ballance = int.Parse(cell.Text);
```

The data type for the balance column is decimal(10,2)

Comment: Are you trying to int.Parse something that has a currency symbol?

Comment: Have you tried setting debug break point on the line "int ballance = int.Parse(cell.text);" and checked the value for cell.text when it throws an error?

Comment: i have removed but still does not work

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should have `TableCell cell = e.Row.Cells[2];` rather than `TableCell cell = e.Row.Cells[3];`

Column indexes start at 0, rather than 1.

In your case, this means you are trying to parse the value of the `Notes` field into an `Int`.

---

**EDIT**

You may also find that `DataFormatString="{0:C0}"` formats the number with a currency sign (eg $/£) and it is this character that cannot be converted to an integer.

Adding the breakpoint as suggested will help you identify this problem.

Comment: thanks, i did correct that but still getting the same error

Comment: You need to set a breakpoint on the `int ballance = int.Parse(cell.Text);` line so you can inspect the `cell.Text` value ... that will give you a better idea of what value cannot be parsed into an int.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a Try {} catch {} block around the int.parse statement so that error conversions don't blow up your code.

It doesn't mean that the cell will format correctly though, simply that it wont break.

Alternatively, use int.TryParse method which is usually a better solution. TryParse is definitely faster. It is a little more confusing, so here is an example

```
// See if we can parse the 'text' string.
    // If we can't, TryParse will return false.
    // Note the "out" keyword in TryParse.
    string text1 = "x";
    int num1;
    bool res = int.TryParse(text1, out num1);
    if (res == false)
    {
        // String is not a number.
    }

    // Use int.TryParse on a valid numeric string.
    string text2 = "10000";
    int num2;
    if (int.TryParse(text2, out num2))
    {
        // It was assigned.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code to,

```
protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

  if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
  {
        dynamic dataItem = e.Row.DataItem; 
        if(dataItem != null && dataItem.Remaining_Ballance < 0)
        {
             e.Row.Cells[2].BackColor = Color.Red;
        }    
    }
}
```

Note: I am using dynamic data type for dataItem as I do not know your actual object type. You should use your actual data type and also need to do casting.

Comment: i am getting this error: System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a definition for 'Remaining_Ballance

Comment: Have you converted dataItem to the object you are binding your gridview to? Can you show me your code where you are binding your gridView datasource so I can modify my code accordingly.